# Report job scheduling with custom data-source in jasper server 4.5.0

Tags: jasperserver

I am  using Jasperserver 4.5.0 Pro. I have developed a custom data-source for some additional feature. All reports that use this custom DS get executed properly and show the correct output when executed manually. But when the same reports are scheduled using Jasper's report job scheduler, there is some problem with session initiation, and hence the reports do not get executed.

Let me explain this a bit.

1. For manual execution of reports -

As part of custom DS, I had to update the following 2 xmls -

viewReportFlow.xml :
        I updated the action state 'runReport' to use our custom DS executer action bean method 'xmlHttpDsExecuterAction.setUpSession' to start session. Please see the below tag of runReport -

```
<action-state id="runReport" xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
<on-entry>
    <evaluate expression="xmlHttpDsExecuterAction.setUpSession"/>
</on-entry>
<evaluate expression="viewReportActionBean"/>
<transition on="success" to="reportOutput"/>
<on-exit>
    <evaluate expression="xmlHttpDsExecuterPageAction.setIndex"/>
</on-exit>
```

viewReportBeans.xml :
        I defined the executer action beans used in above flow xml here -

```
<bean id="xmlHttpDsExecuterAction" class="com.sigma.reporting.xmlhttpds.XmlHttpDsExecuterAction" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w 3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/> <bean id="xmlHttpDsExecuterPageAction" class="com.sigma.reporting.xmlhttpds.XmlHttpDsExecuterPageAction" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w 3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<property name="requestParameterPageIndex" value="pageIndex"/>
<property name="flowAttributePageIndex" value="pageIndex"/>
<property name="xmlHttpDataSourceName" value="com.sigma.reporting.xmlhttpds.XmlHttpDsExecuterDataSourceService"/>
<property name="repository">
    <ref bean="repositoryService"/>
</property>
<property name="jasperPrintName" value="jasperPrintName"/>
<property name="reportUnitObject" value="reportUnitObject"/> </bean>
```

1. For job scheduling of reports :
       I want to implement similarly as above using scheduler. During my investigations, I have tried to analyze the scheduler flow, and tried to put our changes, but no luck so far. Can any one please let me know what flows are used for running reports via scheduler and also please recommend the places to configure custom DS as above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after understanding the flow of japser server scheduler i have got the solution for this.
For setting your custom data source beans and calling the function,we need to specify the bean destination in `$JASPER_HOME/apache-tomcat/weaaps/jasperserver-pro/WEBINF/flows/reportJobBeans.xml` and we can use this bean in ***reportJobFlow.xml*** in **jobOutput** tag lik this

```xml
 <view-state id="jobOutput" view="modules/reportScheduling/jobOutput">
        <on-entry>
            <set name="flowScope.prevForm" value="'jobOutput'"/>
            <evaluate expression="reportOptionsJobEditAction.setOutputReferenceData"/>
            <evaluate expression="xmlHttpDsExecuterAction.setUpSession"/>
        </on-entry>
 </view-state>
```